# Silk classical guitar string gauge is too big for bridge holes

Tags: strings, maintenance, classical-guitar, bridge, string-gauge

My classical guitar has a plastic bridge with pre-drilled or precast holes gauged for standard nylon classical strings.

I got some silk strings which are a bit higher gauge and don’t all fit by just small amounts.

Can I drill plastic?  It’s hard to even get a drill at the right angle.  Or is there another tool?

Comment: Because of the position of the bridge and angle of the holes on a classical guitar it is difficult to position a drill to make the holes larger without the body of the guitar getting in the way. You may even damage the guitar if you’re not careful. It’s not worth it for a set of strings.

Comment: I got 5 of the strings in and tied properly.  Used some oil on a couple ends.  The lowest string is strung in a weird way but has held for 2 weeks.  So all strings are set up, even if one is tied weirdly.

Comment: I’m glad you made it work. I was going to suggest a very small diameter round file if you could even find one.

Comment: It could also be a good idea to take it to a luthier; if the holes can be enlarged safely, then they can do it.